# Create column value based on marker

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In my df I have a marker column which has markers at different timestamps indicated by *. Based on this marker I already assigned Laps:

```
marker = "*" 
marker_indexes = test_data.index[test_data['Marker'] == marker].tolist()

lap_count = 1  # Initialize the 'Lap' count
for i in range(0, len(marker_indexes), 5):
    start_index = marker_indexes[i]
    end_index = min(marker_indexes[i + 4], len(resampled) - 1)
    test_data.loc[start_index:end_index, 'Lap'] = lap_count
    lap_count += 1
```

based on marker_indexes, I want to create a new column called incline which assigns a value of [1.1, 3,7, 1.2, 0]:

```
marker_indexes =[36,
 118,
 240,
 317,
 348,
 370,
 488,
 609,
 694,
 725,
 746,
 880,
 1003,
 1097,
 1131,
 1160,
 1281,
 1404,
 1500,
 1536,
 1561,
 1694,
 1819,
 1920,
 1951]
```

So my goal output would be to fill the ranges between the marker_index with the incline like below :

```
marker_index    Lap incline
          36    1   1.1
           …    1   1.1
         118    1   1.1
         119    1   3
          …     1   3
         240    1   3
         241    1   7
          …     1   7
         317    1   7
         318    1   1.2
          …     1   1.2
         348    1   1.2
         349    1   0
          …     1   0
         370    1   0
```

and then start the same process again for Lap 2 etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a column in a pandas df with a repeated sequence of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314407/add-a-column-in-a-pandas-df-with-a-repeated-sequence-of-values)

Comment: Sorry this does not seem like this works for my aim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach seems to work for my request by creating a dictionary which maps each marker index to its corresponding incline value. By iterating through idx in marker_indexes along i. With modulo I tried to assign incl_list values accordingly to its order

```
# Define incline values 
incl_list = [1.1, 3.0, 7.0, 1.2, 0.0]

# Create a 'marker_names' dictionary by mapping all marker indexes to incline values
marker_names = {idx: incl_list[i % len(incl_list)] for i, idx in enumerate(marker_indexes)}

test_data['incl'] = pd.Series(test_data.index.map(marker_names), index=test_data.index).ffill()
```